# what is difference between spweb and spcontext in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

what is the difference spweb and spcontext when we need to use webcontext 
Plese anyone can answer me.

```
spweb web =spcontext.current.web;
```

and

```
using(spsite site= new spsite(""))
{
using(spweb web=site.openweb(""))
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In it's simplistic terms

```
using(spsite site= new spsite(""))
    {
    using(spweb web=site.openweb(""))
    {
    }
    }
```

The above is pretty much the same as

```
spweb web =spcontext.current.web;
```

However the top code snippet you need to justify a URL to get your site object and by using the

```
using(){
}
```

You are automatically disposing of the objects site and web object.

The

```
spweb web =spcontext.current.web;
```

Get the context of the current web that the code is running in. It is essential that you do NOT dispose of this object.

It all depends if your code is running in the context of the site that you need a web or site object of.